# GPRS Modem to Remote server communication

Tags: communication, modem, gprs

I want to use a GPRS modem with my microcontroller device (not computer) and on request from

my computer located in remote location, the modem has to send data from attached device to my

remote PC. My doubts are

1. Whether any specific GPRS modem is required for this purpose
2. How to get Static IP or Can we able to get static IP for modem.
3. What type of communication can be established between remote server and GPRS modem

for data collection and communication

Thanks in advance.

Eventhough some posts were already there, it doesn't provide the needful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend you use a  Sierra Wireless/ or Wavecom Fasttrack Supreme modem with RS232 port.

For static IP get a APN sim card, but rather let the modem transmit to your PC via Dynamic DNS.

Hope this helps